# How to use the same Apple push notification certificate of the older version for a new version of app

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications

I have a app on app-store which is in production.

I started to make a new version of the app from scratch, i.e., new design and programming style. So, a kind of a whole new project.

Now, I want to use the same certificate that my older version was using for push notifications.

I am using the same bundle `ID`. I have the `.p12` and `.pem` file of the older version of the app also.

Please help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use same Certificates as certificates are related to an account..& uploading a version will just require a new incremented version which can be uploaded with same signing identities for distribution of app & in same way same push certificate will work for sending push messages.

Comment: your solution is right ... it was just that i already had done it .... the real problem was i had to call an API also ..... which the server didn't tell me about ....btw Thanks